# Trouble in auto-complete using Typeahead

Tags: javascript, php, html, typeahead.js

I followed a youtube tutorial on how to use Typeahead.js to auto-complete a form. But it didn't seem to work. Am I missing something? or some changes in dependencies? Here's what I have tried now.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='main.php' method="get" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="users" name="user" placeholder="Subject Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js" />
<script src="js/typeahead.js" />
<script src="js/search.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

JS
**search.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var users = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'result.php?query=%QUERY'﻿,
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    users.initialize();

    alert(users);

    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint:true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength:1
    }, {
        name: 'user',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```

PHP
**result.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!isset($_GET['query'])) {
    echo json_encode([]);
    exit();
}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test','root','');

$users = $db->prepare("
SELECT code,name from sample where name LIKE :query");

$users->execute([
    'query' => "{$_GET['query']}%"
]);

echo json_encode($users->fetchAll());

?>
```

And SQL contains table called sample and two fields, code(subject code) and name(subject name). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's it doing or not doing? Have you tested the individual parts, for example if you call the php directly do you get the correct result? Is there anything in the console? Have you tried adding console.log calls to log things so you can tell how far you get?

Comment: Im sorry I didnt add those details. I get correct results on calling the PHP quering the PHP directly. i.e **result.php?query=A** yields all courses starting with A. But on the HTML I'm not yielding any autocomplete results.

Comment: Sorry there was an editing problem in the question. I happened to solve this by downloading typeahead.bundle.js and latest jQuery plugins. There might be some depency issues after all.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I notice in:

```
$('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead({
```

you're specifying an element with `class` `typeahead` in an element with `id` `prefetch`, but you don't have any elements with either that `class` or `id`. Maybe (untested):

```
<form action="main.php" method="get" autocomplete="off" id="prefetch">
  <input type="text" id="users" name="user" placeholder="Subject Name" class="typeahead">
```